# CallKit ignore the value set on proximityMonitoringEnabled

Tags: ios, iphone, proximity, callkit

I had a voip app which uses call kit. When a call is started I enabled proximity monitor.

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].proximityMonitoringEnabled = YES;
```

When a video stream is added I disabled the proximity monitor. The problem is that the screen is still turn black when I get my phone near to my ear even the proximityMonitoringEnabled is set to NO.

Note if I disable call kit, the proximity monitor is working as expected.
 One more strange thing is if i remove proximityMonitoringEnabled  from my code and enable call kit, the screen is turning black when I get my phone near to my ear, during the call.
I am facing this issue on an iPhone 7 iOS 11.0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use disable/enable proximity monitoring during the call using `AVAudioSession`. To disable proximity monitoring setup mode `AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat`, to enable it use `AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat`. Be careful, these modes works only with `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`.

P.S. I don't think that it is important, but tested only with `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.rawValue == 0`

Answer (score 2):

You can't change this behavior, video calls are still considered calls so the proximity sensor is always on. This is the expected behavior, even my Android phone does this on a Hangouts video call.

Comment: I have noticed with the latest iOS versions (11.2+), that even activating the speaker, Callkit still does not disable the sensor.  If you experience the same issue you should file a bug via the developer portal.  The more bugs filed on the same issue by developers, the attention it is likely to get.